# com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: ERROR: Command execution failure

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver, selenium-rc

com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: ERROR: Command execution failure. Please search the user group at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/selenium-users for error details from the log window.  The error message is: Object doesn't support property or method 'createEvent'

I am getting the above error, somebody please help me out on this issue.

Help will be appreciated.

```
SeleniumServer server = new SeleniumServer(rcc);
DefaultSelenium selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 1212, "*iexploreproxy", "http://");

server.start();
selenium.start();
selenium.windowMaximize();
selenium.open("URL");
selenium.waitForPageToLoad("25000");
selenium.windowMaximize();
selenium.type("id=lgnLogin_UserName", "dy4cl");
selenium.type("id=lgnLogin_Password", "Test1234");
selenium.click("lgnLogin_LoginButton");
selenium.waitForPageToLoad("10000");
String msg = selenium.getText("//table[@id='lgnLogin']/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[4]/td");
System.out.println(msg);
```

Comment: Can you show us some code where you were getting this error? browser name version, selenium version etc?

Comment: I am getting the following error                               Exception in thread "main" com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: ERROR: Command execution failure. Please search the user group at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/selenium-users for error details from the log window.  The error message is: Object doesn't support property or method 'createEvent'at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.throwAssertionFailureExceptionOrError(HttpCommandProcessor.java:97) at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.doCommand(HttpCommandProcessor.java:91) at

Comment: com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium.type(DefaultSelenium.java:291) at first.main(first.java:19)

Comment: i am getting the error are line selenium.type("id=lgnLogin_UserName", "dy4cl");

Comment: i am using IE10 browser, Selenium version 2.21 and Windows7. My Application supports only IE

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade your Selenium Server file to 2.32.0. you can download it from [here](http://selenium.googlecode.com/files/selenium-server-standalone-2.32.0.jar)

Let me know if you are still facing the same issue.

Comment: Thanks Hemachandra, the issue resolved for me. but i am not able to Login to application after giving the Username and Password. It gives the error as Element Logout not found.

Comment: u r telling that you are unable to login and the error is Element Logout not found. I think you need to correct your question.

Comment: its because of IE settings. i have modified the setting, it worked. Thanks

Comment: i am getting the same issue in another system, here i am using Selenium Server version 2.32.0, windows 7, IE10 browser. Java version 1.6

Comment: Is it the same error `Exception in thread "main" com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: ERROR: Command execution failure.` ?

Comment: It seems to be a permission error. can you remove the protected mode for your IE ?